# How can my code know if the client/browser has received the session id yet?

Tags: php, ajax, session

When creating a session and storing data into it, if the session id has not yet been returned to the client, then multiple calls from the client to the server will result in different data showing in the `$_SESSION` object.

For example:

1. Client uses ajax to request a page: "/very_slow.php"
2. "very_slow.php" sets a session variable: `$_SESSION[ "status" ] = "started"`
3. "very_slow.php" then starts doing something that takes 30-40 seconds
4. Client uses ajax to immediately call another page: "/check_session_variable.php" that checks `$_SESSION[ "status" ]`

If step #2 had to create the session (`session_start();`) but has not yet returned to the client, then step #4 will not see the new value in `$_SESSION[ "status" ]`.

So I need to be able to check whether the client has a session id yet. How do I do this?

Checking `session_id()` doesn't work, because if any code has called `session_start()`, then I'll get a value returned even if the client hasn't yet received it in a response.

Comment: Why not create a session when the website is requested? This will always happen before any AJAX calls!

Comment: @MarcoAlka That's a good idea. I think I'll do that.

Comment: glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before *Client uses ajax to request a page: "/very_slow.php"* the client probably opened a page with some HTML and Javascript, which makes the ajax request. Start the session there. Session ID will be sent to the client as HTTP header and will be used by xhr on step 1. It will guarantee session cookie for steps 1..4.

Comment: _“It will guarantee session cookie for steps 1..4”_ – as long as the client _accepts_ cookies. If not, two subsequent AJAX requests will still each start a fresh session on the server. Making the session id available to the JS code directly (putting it into a JS variable), and then supplying it explicitly as a GET/POST parameter in the AJAX requests could mitigate that. (By how much that would increase the potential attack vector, please go research yourselves.)

Comment: Very valid point, but I would rather reject a request without session on step 1 than play with request parameters.

Comment: That would be a way to handle that too, yeah. But that check would have to be made before `session_start` is called, because if that finds either no session id at all, or it gets a (maybe faked) one, for which no session data exists, it would create a new session id automatically. (So if getting passed fake session ids would be a concern, I’d guess you would have to check if the session data file still exists under the session save_path.)